# some questions about University LIBSYS system

Tags: database, database-design, reference

When I did a search on its library system using the term "Software Engineering" as the keyword. The first entry of the search result appears as follows:

BOOK
Software engineering
Ian Sommerville 1951- | 9th ed., International ed.. | c2011
Available at Bundoora Library Bundoora General NEW LOCATION Level 2 (005.1 S6977 )

Which database provides the above information? And what it is(005.1 S6977 ), is kind of indexing?

Answer (score 0):

The information is provided by the catalogue system of the library that you searched in.  Every library has its own catalogue system.  You'd have to ask the librarian which system they use.  There are very, very many of them.  In your case it sounds like it's probably Libsys (www.libsys.co.in)

`005.1` is the Dewey Decimal System classification code for Computer Programming.  Dewey Decimal often specifies a title within its category by using the first letter of the surname of the author - which in your example would be "S" - so that's consistent - followed by a more or less arbitrary number, which is used to store the book physically on a shelf in catalog number order.  While this looks like it could be a Dewey Decimal number, it might be some other classification that is based on or similar to Dewey.  Again, your librarian could tell you what classification they use.